# Content system patterns repository

Tags: information-architecture

Does a pattern library for content systems exist?

I think that content systems for group interaction like wikis, forums (Reddit-styled or traditional), message feeds, chats (Slack), blogs, link directories (Yahoo/DMOZ), and Q&A's (like StackExchange) are not fundamentally different from each other.

They can be modelled as composed of shared "classes" of objects (post, comments, likes, etc.) with various relationships connecting them.

Comment: This isn't really a question we can give a useful answer to. Asking 'does something exist' the answer is either 'yes' or 'no'. Neither are useful answers. And even if some do exist, that doesn't mean any of them are any good.

Comment: Fair point. I would like to phrase my question so that the community can point to resources that are similar to a catalog of content system design patterns. Being aware of such resources can be useful to those who are looking to design their own content systems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have a look at mailchimp:

- https://styleguide.mailchimp.com for copywriting guidelines
- https://ux.mailchimp.com for design guidelines